# Does it need to add a hyphen?

Tags: punctuation

In the following sentence, does it need to add a hyphen between 'cleaning' and 'up' as an adjective?

> It is a kind of cleaning up job.

Answer (score 1):

If the job involves cleaning every day, I would call it a "cleaning job". "Job" in this case is similar to "occupation" or "regular employment".
If by "job" you are referring to a single occasion, then "cleaning-up job" sounds just fine to me - written with a hyphen. It is an attributative noun, functioning as an adjective. For example, "The party was a success, but we had a big cleaning-up job afterwards".

Answer (score 0):

Clean-up as a noun should have a hyphen ("She helped with the clean-up").  Cleaning up doesn't need one ("He helped with cleaning up the house").

However the sentence still sounds a bit awkward.

Try:
"This job involves a lot of cleaning."
or
"It is a sanitation job."

Comment: I mean "what they do is a kind of cleaning up job".

Comment: I think "cleaning up job" is not really a commonly used category of job in English.  So it might be better to use the category "custodial" or "sanitation'.   But I do see that the phrase "clean-up job" has some use in online job postings.

Comment: To mean, clean-ups are things that happen just once, after some event that necessitates them.  After a party, say, or a couple rock shows a month.  If you're cleaning more regularly, like hotel rooms, or apartments, I would say "the job is cleaning", "hired to do the cleaning", etc.